# Godot script editor font won't change despite setting new ttf file

Tags: text, editor, godot

I can't seem to change the font in Godot's script editor. I want to change it to the monaco_linux.ttf I downloaded. I've specified which file to use, but the font only seems to increase in size a bit when I set it.

*How can I change the font in Godot's script editor?*

**Editor Font Setting:**

> Editor >> Editor Settings >> Code Font >> Path/To/ttf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the font wasn't working because I was trying to use size 14 font. When I switched to size 16, it worked fine..